# get postviews under every posts in the main page

Tags: tags

i need to display under every article in the main page, the respective number of post views. I tried with a plugin called wp.postviews but I cant figure out how it's works...it allow only the widget component.

What I have to do to get the postviews? I think I have to use the plugin above and add some extra php code on the index.php

Thanks for help

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba pleeeeeeeeease and again - as answer :) We have enough newbs to educate to not use answers as comments, we don't need experts using comments as answers on top ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(function_exists('the_views')) the_views();
```